# I'm having a hard time on this website due to my equinophobia

Tags: discussion, unicorns

**What were you thinking when you polluted this website with unicorns?**

My entire life has been a struggle against my [equinophobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinophobia), I had to give up with my lifelong dream of becoming a horse-jockey and I ended up being a [grass-mud-horse](https://code.google.com/p/grass-mud-horse/) programmer.

I thought I had finally found my way of living when all of a sudden you come up with this and throw me back into an abyss of depression and fear.

You're horrible people

Comment: It's a conspiracy.

Comment: hey don't worry you have equinophobia not unicophobia !!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Say it after me:

> Unicorns are not horses.

Again.

> Unicorns are not horses.

And again:

> Unicorns are not horses.

Comment: Oh my! Even diamond mods can crack jokes.

Comment: Equine can mean "horse like", in which case, unicorns are definitely equine :)

Comment: **Unicorns are not horses.**

Comment: @devnull - who you callin' a diamond mod?

Comment: He probably got the diamond from having so many unicoins. It's a hidden power up

Comment: @Oded Apologies.  Didn't realize that you are the mod of mods.

Comment: @devnull - nothing like that... just a humble dev

Answer (score 6):

C'mon you're not going to tell me you're scared of this fluffy unicorn =o

[image]

Comment: **OH MY GOODNESS IT MIGHT ROLL OVER ME AND CRUSH ME AAAAAAAAAH**